# Pathogen don't load a little script (in the solarized folder)

Tags: vim, pathogen

I'm trying to have a correct vim configuration with pathogen.
In particular, I installed [solarized](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized) in the bundle folder with the recommanded way :

```
 $ cd vim-colors-solarized/colors
 $ mv solarized.vim ~/.vim/colors/
```

So, I can use the good color theme, and I have the solarized documentation. However, the small script give with solarized [togglebg](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized/blob/master/autoload/togglebg.vim) don't work. It don't map correctly, and I can't call it from the command line. But I don't see what is wrong.

Here is my organization of my bundle folder :

```
- Bundle
      - vim-colors-solarized
          - autoload
              - tooglebg.vim    #(The problematic script)
          - doc 
              - solarized.txt
          - colors
              - solarized.vim
```

Has a vim expert a solution to why the script is not load ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the script is in the `autoload` folder, nothing will be defined by default (only stuff in the `plugin` folder is automaticaly sourced). As described in the documentation, you need to explicitly define a mapping:

```
call togglebg#map("<F5>")
```

or you could move the script to the `plugin` folder.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know the difference between autoload and plugin.